# How to remove small components from a graph

Tags: python, networkx

I'm new to networkx and could do with some help please.

I have a set of data which I've processed to generate the nodes and edges. There are around 5000 groups of nodes that have more than 2 links within them (up to 10 nodes in the group in total). But the problem is that there are also several thousand pairs of nodes that only have 1 edge between them, i.e node a is linked to node b but neither are linked to any other node.

I want to remove these paired nodes from the chart.

Is there a way to filter these out?

Comment: Let me see if I understand: You have a graph, `G` and you want to remove all nodes from `G` that are not part of components of 3 or more nodes?

Comment: Joel - that is a much more elegant way of describing the problem: its exactly that!

Comment: I've edited the title to make it more useful for other people who may find this through a search engine.  Feel free to modify if you don't think I've appropriately changed it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So our goal is to remove all nodes from components with less than 3 nodes (this includes isolated nodes if they exist).

```
for component in list(nx.connected_components(G)):
    if len(component)<3:
        for node in component:
            G.remove_node(node)
```

A small warning is in order when using `nx.connected_components`.  It returns a [generator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1756096/2966723) of components.  If I didn't put `list` around it, it would generate one at a time, and then perform the steps for the given component.  Once all that is done, it would generate the next component.  But because `G` has been modified, python can't be sure that this behaves well.  So it would die (complaining that a dictionary changed size --- the number of nodes in `G` changed).  By turning it into a list, the components are all found before it starts the loop.  So the graph won't be changing while the components are being found.